# How does slice notation work in the context of this matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, syntax

Please could someone help me understand this notation I found in a matplotlib plot? I believe that it is slice notation but can't get my head around it.

```
plt.plot(self.input_indices, inputs[n, :, plot_col_index], label='Inputs', marker='.', zorder=-10)
```

Specifically I don't understand `inputs[n, :, plot_col_index]`

`self.input_indices` is an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6....]

`inputs` is a tensorflow tensor

`n` is an int in range 1-3

`plot_col_index` is the index of the column of the tensor that is being plotted on the y-axis.

I believe the format is plt.plot(x, y ...) but I can't understand how `inputs[n, :, plot_col_index]` translates to a y-value.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `inputs` is a 3D tensor, which you can visualise as 3 individual 2D arrays.

The slice `inputs[n, :, plot_col_index]`  first selects `n`, one of the 3 2D arrays. Then from that 2D array, by indexing `[:, col_index]` you are selecting all the rows for a given column, leaving you with a 1D array (your plot y values), which should be the same length as `self.input_indices` (your plot x values).

[This link](https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/numpy/index-and-slice/) has a nice illustration of selecting data in 3D arrays.